# EINTR and blocking recv call

Tags: c, error-handling, signals, recv

I'm reading http://250bpm.com/blog:12 to understand how EINTR should/could be handled and I have trouble reconciling the second and third source code snippet with description.

Second listing:

```
volatile int stop = 0;

void handler (int)
{
    stop = 1;
}

void event_loop (int sock)
{
    signal (SIGINT, handler);

    while (1) {
        if (stop) {
            printf ("do cleanup\n");
            return;
        }
        char buf [1];
        recv (sock, buf, 1, 0);
        printf ("perform an action\n");
    }
}
```

Third listing:

```
volatile int stop = 0;

void handler (int)
{
    stop = 1;
}

void event_loop (int sock)
{
    signal (SIGINT, handler);

    while (1) {
        if (stop) {
            printf ("do cleanup\n");
            return;
        }
        char buf [1];
        int rc = recv (sock, buf, 1, 0);
        if (rc == -1 && errno == EINTR)
            continue;
        printf ("perform an action\n");
    }
}
```

Specifically:

> POSIX specification defines that when signal (such as Ctrl+C) is caught, recv  returns EINTR error. That allows the event loop to wrap over and check the 'stop' variable:

But the explanation given for supposed blocking in 2nd listing is that:

> The problem is that recv is a blocking function. If Ctrl+C is pressed
>   while the event loop is blocked in recv, you'll get a kind of
>   deadlock: Signal handler is executed as expected, it sets 'stop' to 1,
>   but then the execution blocks. The event loop is stuck in recv and has
>   no opportunity to check whether 'stop' was set to 1.

Well, signal handler is defined in both cases and so the `SIGINT` is caught, therefore it seems like `recv` should unblock in both cases, no?

Comment: Red a little further... Under the third example it says "EDIT: Please note that to make blocking fuctions like recv return EINTR you may have to use sigaction() with SA_RESTART set to zero instead of signal() on some operating systems." The semantics of the `signal` function is unfortunately different on different systems.

Comment: This passage explains what would happen if EINTR didn't exist.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I understand that, but presuming we stay on the same system and use `sigaction()` or that `signal()` call is enough to make recve return `EINTR`, the behavior of both snippets should be the same (whether they block or not block actually)

Comment: It would be *almost* the same, because in the first example (in your question) you do not check for errors, and will "perform an action" even if `recv` was interrupted.

Comment: Both examples shown here introduce a race. `SIGINT` would not necessarily break the loop in both cases. Signals (used alone) are a bad choice for synchronisation.

Comment: @alk OK, so how would you solve this problem here?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: again that's true, but at the same time it does not make a difference with the main problem here, i.e. does `recv` get interrupted with `EINTR` on program catching signal or not, no?

Comment: Regarding the return from a blocking call to `recv()` both snippets you show behave the same.

Comment: `stop` should be typed `sig_atomic_t` not `int`, BTW.

Comment: I went through the 250bpm blog in the original post. Personally I have a feeling that the code examples there do not support the arguments in a clear, logical way.